# How can I make my web app iPhone 5 compatible?

Tags: ios, web-applications, safari, iphone

I have a website optimized as a web app with iOS safari, so that adding to home screen opens the app in a separate Webview. However, it always opens in the 3.5" letter boxed mode, instead of stretching to fill the screen. I know that with native apps, you just have to add the iPhone 5 sized launch image. How can I do this for a web app?

Comment: I just noticed this as well. I don't have an answer, but I imagine it's an oversight on Apple's part (and can't be fixed until they update iOS).

Comment: rdar://12401823 http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2068403

Comment: @WillHenderson Check [this blog post](http://taylor.fausak.me/2012/09/20/iphone-5-web-app-startup-image/) out. It indicates that if you remove `width=device-width` from the viewport, it doesn't letterbox it. It worked for me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found on [this post](http://taylor.fausak.me/2012/09/20/iphone-5-web-app-startup-image/) that all that is required is that you remove `width=device-width` from the viewport meta tag. The blog talks about specifying a startup image, but this appears to be optional.

**Edit:** Original source of answer is [Max Firtman](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/iphone-5-ios-6-html5-developers). He indicates it may be a bug as well (see comments), but for now, this solution works.

Comment: You, sir, just made my day ;-) +1