# Webapp on iphone 5 shows wrong height

Tags: html, css, web-applications, viewport

I always get the wrong measurements of my webapp. It is 320x460 even though I'd expect it to be 320x548.

I'm using following metatags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help you -

standard viewport tag to set the viewport to the device's width
Android 2.3 devices need this so 100% width works properly and
doesn't allow children to blow up the viewport width

```
<meta name="viewport" id="vp" content="initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,width=device-width" />
```

width=device-width causes the iPhone 5 to letterbox the app, so
we want to exclude it for iPhone 5 to allow full screen apps

```
<meta name="viewport" id="vp" content="initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1" media="(device-height: 568px)" />
```

Comment: The magic needed was to delete the bookmark and open a new one. Somehow the "app" thought it had to display the addressbar.